# How to iterate over variable and set its name dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to iterate over variable and set its name dynamically using for loop. However it gives syntax error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [(…)

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var i += i + "<br>";
}
```

Comment: You need to create `text` as an array, eg `var text = [];`, then add the items to it either via index or using the `push()` method.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `var text[i]`?

Comment: No actually I want to set it as a variable not array.

Comment: `text[i]` is an array.

Comment: It should output number  var1 = 1, var 2 = 2 , var 3 = 3..

Comment: Then do you mean, `text` is a string with `1,2,3...` as its contents?

Comment: Check my updated comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a variable name dynamically then you can use bracket notation on the `window` object:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    window['text' + i] = i + "<br>";
}
console.log(text3); // = '3<br>'
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/50my92sj/)

However, this is not good practice at all. A better method would be to use an object to achieve the same thing:

```
var myDynamicVars = {};
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    myDynamicVars['text' + i] = i + "<br>";
}
console.log(myDynamicVars.text3); // = '3<br>'
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/50my92sj/1/)

A better method still would be to just use the original array where required without creating the variables at all.